# Dismiss alert dialog builder from onpause

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to display an alert dialog with two buttons. But if the dialog is not disissed when the activity is paused it throws an error. I know you can dismiss a dialog using .dismiss but this is an AlertDialog Builder not a Dialog. Any idea how to do this?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Title");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Message");

                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        //yes
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });

                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //no                
                    dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: what about dialog.cancel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the AlertDialog when showing the dialog:

```
dialog = alertDialog.show(); // show and return the dialog
```

Then in the onPause you can dismiss the AlertDialog:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The dialog needs to be defined as instance variable for this to work:

`private AlertDialog dialog;  // instance variable`

BTW the AlertDialog.Builder is a builder because you can use the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) like so:

```
dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Title");
    .setMessage("Message")
[...]
    .show();
```

Comment: I found that this did not work for me because alertDialog.show(); returns void instead of the expected AlertDialog. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: This answer is exactly what the original question stated that wasn't working. AlertDialog is not always an option, so the AlertDialog.Builder is the alternative; however, this answer does not apply to AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: @Rodrigo Mesquita you didn't read the answer. My answer is that you get the AlertDialog when you show the dialog from the AlertDialog.Builder. Once you got the AlertDialog you can dismiss the dialog. It's not possible to dismiss the AlertDialog.Builder. The link you  mention does exactly what I describe in my answer. The fact that this is the accepted answer might be an indicator that it answers the OPs question.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin, I looked at both your answer and mine again after a few days, and I still think it's a bit confusing since you initialized the "dialog" object twice. What you wrote below the "BTW" part worked for me, but the top part did confuse me. And the fact that this is the accepted answer just means that some people understood it, but not everyone. I think you could get more votes up if you tried to simplify it.

Comment: I don't initialize it twice. The fact it's the accepted answer has nothing to do with ppl understanding it but with it answering the op's question (the upvotes do though). I will clarify the answer once I'm at a computer.